# Xamarin: ObservableCollection does't automatically update ListView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView bounded to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel. 
In initialization the ListView items are displayed perfectly.
However, when I try to update a single value of an item of ObservableCollection at run-time, the linked item in the listview does not update automatically. It updates only if I scroll the listView. Why does it behave like this?

Here's the code:

**XAML**

```
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame Style="{StaticResource frameListView}" >
                            <StackLayout Margin="-15">

                                <Label Text="{Binding Articolo.Descrizione}"
                                       Style="{StaticResource labelDescrizioneStyle}" />

                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center">

                                        <Button x:Name="removeButton" 
                                                VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                Text="-"
                                                Font="20"
                                                WidthRequest="45" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                Style="{StaticResource buttonNeutroStyle}"  
                                                Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference mieiAcquistiStack}, Path=BindingContext.AggiungiCommand}"                                                   
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />       

                                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

                                            <Label Text="{Binding QtaEdit}" 
                                                   TextColor="Black"
                                                   FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                   WidthRequest="40"
                                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                        </StackLayout>

                                        <Button x:Name="addButton" 
                                                VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                Text="+"
                                                WidthRequest="45" FontAttributes="Bold"   
                                                Style="{StaticResource buttonNeutroStyle}"   
                                                Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference mieiAcquistiStack}, Path=BindingContext.AggiungiCommand}"   
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
        public static ObservableCollection<RigaStoricoModel> acquistiList;
        public ObservableCollection<RigaStoricoModel> AcquistiList
        {
            get { return acquistiList; }
            set
            {
                if (acquistiList != value)
                {
                    acquistiList = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private void AggiungiArticolo(RigaStoricoModel prodotto, ParametriUM parametriUM)
        {
            double esistenzaUMPredef = parametriUM.EsistenzaUMPredef.GetValueOrDefault(0);

            if (esistenzaUMPredef > 0)
            {
                double qtaMinima = parametriUM.QtaMinima.GetValueOrDefault(1);

                if (prodotto.QtaEdit + qtaMinima <= esistenzaUMPredef)
                {
                    prodotto.QtaEdit += qtaMinima;  // <-- here the update not working
                }
            }
```

Comment: Updates that are related to the collection itself are being managed by the `Observablecollection`'s `INotifyCollectionChanged` event. Updates that are related to an object inside the collection should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and bound properly. So, does `RigaStoricoModel` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Show us that code.

Comment: Thx. Now it works. I missed to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to `RigaStoricoModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

If so, you should achieve the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `RigaStoricoModel` as Silvermind's said.

Here is `MyViewModel.cs` code.

```
   public class RigaStoricoModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private double _qtaEdit;
        public double QtaEdit
        {
            set
            {

                _qtaEdit = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("QtaEdit");

            }
            get => _qtaEdit;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I used `AggiungiCommand` to make a test(decrease or increase).

```
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<RigaStoricoModel> acquistiList;
        public ObservableCollection<RigaStoricoModel> AcquistiList
        {
            get { return acquistiList; }
            set
            {
                if (acquistiList != value)
                {
                    acquistiList = value;
                  //  OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public ICommand AggiungiCommand { protected set; get; }
        public ICommand AggiungiCommand2 { protected set; get; }

        //  public int MyProperty { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            AcquistiList = new ObservableCollection<RigaStoricoModel>();
            AcquistiList.Add(new RigaStoricoModel() { QtaEdit=0.28 });
            AcquistiList.Add(new RigaStoricoModel() { QtaEdit = 0.38 });
            AcquistiList.Add(new RigaStoricoModel() { QtaEdit = 0.48 });
            AcquistiList.Add(new RigaStoricoModel() { QtaEdit = 0.58 });
            AcquistiList.Add(new RigaStoricoModel() { QtaEdit = 0.68 });

            AggiungiCommand2=new Command(async (key) =>
            {
                RigaStoricoModel model = key as RigaStoricoModel;
                model.QtaEdit += 0.1;

            });
            AggiungiCommand = new Command(async (key) =>
            {
                RigaStoricoModel  model= key as RigaStoricoModel;
                model.QtaEdit -= 0.1;

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is layout.xaml(I do not have this style, for testing,I delete them and adjust this layout).

```
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AcquistiList}" x:Name="mieiAcquistiStack" HasUnevenRows="True" >

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate> 
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame  >
                            <StackLayout Margin="-15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                                <Label Text="{Binding Articolo.Descrizione}"
                                       />

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center">

                                    <Button x:Name="removeButton" 
                                                VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                Text="-"
                                                Font="20"
                                                WidthRequest="45" FontAttributes="Bold"

                                                Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference mieiAcquistiStack}, Path=BindingContext.AggiungiCommand}"                                                   
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

                                        <Label Text="{Binding QtaEdit}" 
                                                   TextColor="Black"
                                                   FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                   WidthRequest="40"
                                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                    </StackLayout>

                                    <Button x:Name="addButton" 
                                                VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                Text="+"
                                                WidthRequest="45" FontAttributes="Bold"   

                                                Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference mieiAcquistiStack}, Path=BindingContext.AggiungiCommand2}"   
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Here is layout background code.

```
    public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
        }
```

Comment: Excellent. Now it works. I missed to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to `RigaStoricoModel`. Thx very much!